# How to get value from optional variable, and get default value instead if the optional variable is not valid?

Tags: swift

I have code like this that I frequently use:

```
var myName = "Guest"
if let data = dictionary["name"] as? String { myName = data; }
func supply (name: myName)
```

How to make it like this (or similar):

```
guard let myName = dictionary["name"] as? String else { let myName = "Guest" }
func supply (name: myName)
```

I prefer the latter because it involves less variable names and also more straightforward. I have tried the code, but it looks like the `let myName = "Guest"` inside the brackets is limited by the variable scope inside the brackets only. How to make it possible? Thanks.

Comment: Use a nil-coalescer.
```let myName = (dict["name"] as? String) ?? "Guest"```
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html

Comment: @EricKenny ow I see. And I also can combine the nil-coalescer with the optional typecasting as well. Nice! Please make your comment as answer so I can select it as best answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a nil-coalescing operator.

```
let myName = (dictionary["name"] as? String) ?? "Guest"
```

This will try to unwrap the value for key `"name"` as string and fall back to `"Guest"` in the event there is no value for key `"name"` or if the value cannot be cast as `String`

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html